# Issue with coordinator layout and toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am making a layout where i want my image to be drawn behind the status bar. I am using a coordinator layout for this but have encountered a strange problem.
When i am using the code given below i am able to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcyxJ.png)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/album_art_playing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
.....
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But when i move my toolbar view above the image view i am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa8kL.png) and the layout file looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/album_art_playing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
....
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am unable to understand why moving the toolbar widget above the image view changes the behaviour of the image view and the image is not drawn behind the status bar.  And how can i achieve this. I want my image to be brawn behind the status bar but also want my toolbar title and icon to appear which as of now does not.

Comment: Please properly specify your question.

Comment: I want my image to be displayed behind the status bar but this only happens when i place my toolbar widget above my image view but doing so makes the title and icon present on my toolbar invisible. And when i move my toolbar widget below my image view my toolbar icons and title gets displayed but the image is no longer drawn behind the status bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right,

> perhaps overlapped by the image view.

Because `CoordinatorLayout` extends `FrameLayout` from android [documentation of `CoordinatorLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html)

> CoordinatorLayout is a super-powered FrameLayout.

So it inherits all the properties of `FrameLayout` so whenever you place a view after another view it will overlap the view.

Now comes the main problem 
**Why a white/grey colored status bar is visible when you change the order of toolbar?**

It is because from lollipop or above system can draw a translucent status bar if you use following in your theme  **(This won't work if you're not using this)**

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

so in your first image, it is showing a grey color because you haven't defined a background color of the toolbar(it only considers the view underneath it, in this case, toolbar is underneath it), Just change the color of your toolbar to pink and it will show a preview like this

[image: Colored toolbar]

I think you will get the idea when you change the color of the toolbar.

Just in case if you want a transparent toolbar then you will have to set 100% transparent background color to your toolbar and be sure to set

in `OnCreate` of actvity:

`getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);`

and in your theme:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: Your answer seems satisfying i will try to use a transparent backgrounds for my toolbar and see if it works . Is there any alternative as a parent layout which i can use in my layout so that i will be able to draw behind status bar. I don't really need a coordinator layout but relative and linear layout does not fit its children behind status bar so i am using a coordinator layout.

Comment: @AshutoshPatoa don't use a transparent background, this is what you're currently using. Use a colored toolbar.

Comment: But if i use a colored toolbar then my image will not be visible it will be overlapped by the coloured toolbar and i want my image to be drawn behind the status bar

Comment: ohh @AshutoshPatoa right then you'll have to use 100% transparent status bar and also set some flag before activity's oncreate method...

Comment: Yeah i am know that thanks for your help. Can you please edit your answer and mention about using a transparent toolbar so that i can mark it correct and others will get benefited

Comment: @AshutoshPatoa yeah, sure.